# Ignoring rotation in pgf decorations

Tags: pgf-decorations

**Edit:** I am interested in how this problem could or could not be solved using pgf decorations, not in how to draw this specific shape.

---

I am trying to use pgf line decorations to draw dotted lines, where the dots are squares, as in:

[image: Correct line behaviour]

However pgf automatically rotates the environment in which the squares are drawn as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{Squares}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=10pt]{
    \fill (0cm,0cm) rectangle (5pt,5pt);
  }
  \state{final}{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration=Squares] (0,0) -- (5,5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which outputs this:

[image]

Is there a way to either compensate for the automatic rotation, or alternately disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate your `\fill` decoration command by the opposite of the rotation upon entering the decoration code (given by `\pgfdecoratedangle`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{Squares}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=10pt]{
    \fill[rotate=-\pgfdecoratedangle] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (5pt,5pt);
  }
  \state{final}{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration=Squares] (0,0) -- (1,5);
    \draw[decorate,decoration=Squares] (0,0) -- (5,5);
    \draw[decorate,decoration=Squares] (0,0) to[out=0,in=-90] (5,5);
    \draw[decorate,decoration=Squares] (0,0) -- (5,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]